# Adding values in List<String> dynamically

Tags: java

Every time a new String is generated but the List is having null value for it.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{add.periods}" var="prd">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{prd}"  /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{add.addList}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{add.submit}" />
</h:dataTable>
```

Entity AddPeriods: object add

```
private List<String> periods = new ArrayList<String>();
    @ElementCollection
     public List<String> getPeriods() 
     {         
            return periods;
     }
        public void setPeriods(List<String> periods)      
        {

         this.periods=periods;
         }

         public void addList() 
         { 

          periods.add(new String());

         }
          public void submit()
          {
          System.out.println("periods..................................: " +periods);
           }
```

Message on Console:After 2 times addition

```
    periods..................................: [, ]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not adding a *null* value (it's not a null reference) - but it's not adding a *useful* value:

```
periods.add(new String());
```

In what way were you expecting that to be useful? Shouldn't you be adding *a useful string value* instead of just a new empty string?

Comment: I am just entering a string like abc.One more thing whenever I click add Button  the value added previously become null I mean the textbox becomes empty.

Comment: @kanika: But you're not adding that string into the list - you're just adding a new *empty* string. How did you expect that to work? It's not at all clear what frameworks you're using or how you're *expecting* any user data to make it into your class. I suspect this question is *really* very specific to the UI framework you're using, and you should read the tutorials for that framework. As you haven't even told us what framework it is, there's not a lot more we can do to help you.

Comment: "addList()" is doing addition of a String  into the List for me. What I want is that when user click add button she/he can assign it a value.By the way i am working on "Spring web flow" framework.I also tried following code:private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void add() {
        items.add(new Item());
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("items: " + items);
    }
    @ElementCollection
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<String> Items)   
  {
   
   this.items=items;
  } and it workswell

Comment: @kanika: You need to look at Spring Web Flow tutorials, basically - I can't tell from the code you've provided where the UI data is meant to get into your code.

Comment: from this UIData it is getting store into a List also in Db<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{add.items}" var="item">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{item.value}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="add" action="#{add.add}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{add.submit}" />
    <h:commandButton value="sub" action="submit" />
</h:form>   I am trying to do the same thing with String type objects.

Comment: public class Item implements Serializable {
 /**
  * 
//  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -8521410576022596959L;
 private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return String.format("Item[value=%s]", value);
    }

}

Comment: If this can work well with Item class why I can't do the same thing with String type objects

Comment: @kanika: It's really not clear what your code means, and comments aren't the best place of showing this. I suggest you look at the Spring Web Flow tutorials again and then edit your question to be clearer. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some ideas on how to write a good question.

Comment: I appreciate ur suggestion.I will definitely go through tutorials.Sir, by this tym can u tell me how one can add elements in List<String> dynamically.Thats what i really want.Please its urgent.

Comment: @kanika: Just because something is urgent doesn't mean you can short-cut learning. Adding a string to a `List<String>` is the easy bit - you just call `list.add(value)`. It's getting the value *to* that point which is causing you problems, and that's specific to the Spring Web Framework.

Comment: can u give me a demo,user from a webpage is adding text to UIInput like Period No and its start and end time.What i want is that data entered as start time of lectures get added into a List,another List for adding end timings and one for Period No.

Comment: @kanika: No, I can't - because it's specific to Spring Web Flow which I'd never used. But there's plenty of documentation and I'm sure there are sample applications...

Answer (score 2):

You just add a new empty string. Switch it to something else, e.g:

```
periods.add(new String("hey there!"));
```

Comment: I want a new String to be added by the user.Here "hey there" will be a pre-defined one.One more thing when I write  <h:column><h:inputText value="#{add.periods[0]}"  /></h:column>,my value gets stored at index zero,Message at console becomes:  periods..................................: [//value entered in textbox, ]

Comment: Why would you want to call the string constructor with a literal in this case? ;)

Comment: I tried ur code it results periods..................................: [hey there!,hey there!,hey there! ] ,but i want the value to be user defined.It is not accepting my changes.Please clarify my point whenever i press "add" button  "addList()" get called which returns  a String type object right.Now what I want is that a user can assign a value to it.Then it will get stored into a List.Why in this case I am not able to reassign a value to "hey there!" string.

Answer (score 1):

Pass some String to the function addList, else it will keep on adding empty Strings to the list. When you write something like, `periods.add(new String("Kanika"))`, and its added in List as many times as you press add button, that means your function is working fine. But unless and until you will pass something to it, it will not insert anything meaningful.

Comment: but sir it will be a value defined by me i want it to be user-defined

Comment: That's what I meant when I said `Pass Some String to the Function`. Currently you are calling it like `add.addList` i.e with no parameters. Check the way of passing the parameter using the framework you are working with. and then use the corresponding syntax.